# Chromecast not detectable from chromium

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, chromecast

I'm using mint 18 and chromium 55. I have chromecast set up and connected to the network. I can connect to it from my Android device but the chromium browser can't find it. I tried resetting the mediarouter and I have seen that the extension for chromecast is discontinued and I can't install it.

Anything else I can do?

Comment: No fix yet: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1621753

Comment: currently works perfectly with my chromecast and Chromium
Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on LinuxMint 19 (64-bit) no changes or plug-ins needed

Answer (score 23):

> To resolve this issue you need to enable chrome://flags/#load-media-router-component-extension

[Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1694437#p1694437)

Comment: After enabling this, my Chromium cannot restart anymore... Crash and exit immediately without asking as the main window popup. At last, I have to `rm ~/.config/chromium` to make Chromium available again.

Comment: Hi there, this bug exists indeed. You have two solutions : 1) if you use chromium you don't need to remove `~/.config/chromium`. You just need to launch `chromium --disable-extensions` once, close it, and then relaunch chromium normally. 2) Use google chrome which works perfectly with chromecast

Comment: Yes, finally I installed google-chrome and finally can find chromcast.

Comment: This helped me on Windows too with chromium v72, I guess it's a Chromium issue not a linux one

Answer (score 5):

I had to enable `#load-media-router-component-extension` and `#cast-media-route-provider` (well, actually, I don't know if only the last one made it work or both, I've been trying different things for a while). Both flags can be found in `chrome://flags`.

Comment: Needed both too. Chromium Version 80.0.3987.149 Debian 10.3

Comment: Just needed the second - `#cast-media-route-provider`; Arch Linux, Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit). Also had to start `avahi-daemon.service` for VLC to see it.